# Xamarin - Android Google maps displaying blank grids : Map is not loading

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.android, nuget

I created a tabbed application with 4 tabs. Inside one Child activity I need to display Google Maps upon clicking on a button.

I am using the Xamarin.GooglePlayservices.Maps NuGet package to the solution

I have followed the required steps and generated the API Key.
I have enabled Google Maps Android API v2 in API console.
In my manifest file there are all required permissions too. 
But don't know what's going wrong. Here is my code snippet.

### My Map Activity

```
[Activity (Label = "MapViewActivity")]
public class MapViewActivity : Activity
{
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
{
base.OnCreate (bundle);
SetContentView (Resource.Layout.upcoming_exits_mapview);
}
}
```

### upcoming_exits_mapview.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.mypackage">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />

 <!-- Google Maps for Android v2 will cache map tiles on external storage -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<permission android:name="com.mypackage.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.mypackage.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<application android:name="RBApplication" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" android:label="RoadBrake" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-wupcG-pyzIwP2FPkc" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

Comment: How are you signing your app? Make sure the keystore you are using matches the signature you have told the Developer Console you are using. If you are signing your app using the debug keystore Xamarin provides you will just see an empty grid.

Comment: I tried using the signed keystore as you suggested. This is the second version of the app,so I used the previous version API  Key from developer console. But result the same it displays blank grids. @ Cheesebaron

Comment: Finally able to show the maps but still not 100%.
1. Regenerated API KEY in developer console for previous version.
2. Now when blank grids came, touching on the screen shows maps.
 
Can Anybody suggest what's going on??????

Comment: What device is this on?

Comment: Nexus 4 as well Nexus 5 too

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the problem ! It is the problem with Tabbed application. Tried showing mapview outside of tab, it worked without fail. Inside a tab, some features are not working as expected in Android.